# Creating a single large bitmap from OpenStreetMap

Tags: windows, gratis, images, maps, openstreetmap

I need a high resolution image of a map from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org). The resolution has to be much higher than the one of my monitor, so I can't simply take a screenshot.

A similar functionality already exists with [BigMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap), however, it does not create the Bitmap online, but instead it creates a Perl script that you then run on your own PC to do the actual work (likely: downloading tiles from the Internet). I didn't manage to do that on Windows.

I need something similar that

- runs on Windows
- is gratis, preferably Open Source
- allows me to input a target rectangle (I could even do that manually without selecting it on an interactive map)
- allows me to define a zoom level or target size
- downloads all the map tiles
- creates a single Bitmap (lossless format, .bmp; .png; .tif)

Comment: Do you mean that BigMap requires to run an OpenStreetMap server on your own machine? Or is it just that the perl script did not work as intended?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I assume that the Perl script would download tiles from the Internet.

Comment: Re "(likely: downloading tiles from the Internet)." after having studied the generated Perl code, it does indeed fetch URLs of images and then stitch them together using some math geometry. The "BigMap 2" version seems to allow 4  "exports" as beside Perl you have Python also and 2 others.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (and therefore community wiki), but I'd like to point out that such an app is possible to write (I tried), but it's hard to not violate the terms of use.

1. If you don't do it right, you get a HTTP 429 error with the message "too many requests".
2. If you read about [the policies](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/), you can download tiles, but you'll find that

> [...] downloading an area of over 250 tiles at zoom level 13 or higher for offline or later usage is forbidden. These tiles are generally not available (cached) on the server in advance, and have to be rendered specifically for those requests, putting an unjustified burden on the available resources.

I definitely wanted zoom level 18 and >500 tiles, which is certainly out of the limits.